# React native app crash when chrome debugger is on

Tags: react-native, debugging, plugins, module, crash

I was trying to test a custom module that I created with [react-native-builder-bob](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob). I imported it locally by adding it to the project, and adding the dependencies as "my-test-module": "file:my-test-module", run a `yarn install` and a `pod install`. I correctly imported it in a page and used it inside a function. The module works correctly and everything works fine, until I turn on the Chrome debugger (either in iOS and Android), as soon as I do that I got the following errors.

[image: Screen of the errors: many Invariant Violation]

I already tried every other solution that I found on the web, like deleting `node_module` and `Pods`, running a `watchman watch-del-all` and a `react native start --reset-cache`, clean and rebuilt it natively, but nothing works.

The only way that I am able to debug in this condition is by using [Flipper](https://fbflipper.com/), which is kinda annoying since Chrome is a very useful tool and is more powerful.

Any suggestion please?